# Pulling Breadcrumb items from the Menu Link text instead of Title field (D7)

Tags: routes, panels, breadcrumbs

Some of my pages are pulling text for the last breadcrumb item from the menu link text. The rest of my pages are pulling text for the last breadcrumb item from the Title field. What I want is for all of the breadcrumbs to pull from the menu link text.

I'm using the Menu Breadcrumb module (applied to all of the pages in question) which allows the menu link text of a page to be added to the breadcrumbs, *but I do not have this option enabled*. My theme (a derivative of Omega) must be what's pulling the text into the breadcrumbs (I hear this is not done by default) because when I *do* enable the Menu Breadcrumb option I get either the menu link text *twice* or the menu link text *and* the Title text (depending on which page I look at).

Those pages pulling the breadcrumb item from the menu link text are of a specific content type which has a panel applied to it. The rest aren't using panels -- this is the main difference I can see which might explain this behavior.

I suppose I could alter the theme to not put the text item in, then enable the feature in Menu Breadcrumb (which behaves correctly), but obviously it is possible to do it the way I want without modifying the theme since it's happening with the panel'd type pages.

Any ideas?

Install Stats:

- D7
- Derivative of the Omega theme
- Context
- Panels
- Menu Breadcrumb (used on all pages; [modified](http://drupal.org/node/1372726) - see post by pschnapp)
- Custom Breadcrumb (used only on two types, not the affected types)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since we came to a resolution on this issue, so I hope I get everything right.

It seems that I was a bit confused w.r.t. what fields data was being pulled from for these areas (menu item, title, & breadcrumb item). Here's what we found:

- Menu item text gets pulled from the "Menu link title" field in the "Menu settings" section of a page's editing interface.
- The text in the "Title" field of a type is used for the breadcrumb item text and will be used as the page's title as well (i.e. the title displayed in the browser window's/tab's chrome) if no other title is specified.
- The "Page title" field in the "Page title settings" section will override the "Title" field so far as the browser chrome title is concerned, but won't affect the breadcrumb.

IIRC, the "Page title" field was not active for the pages we were having trouble with, which was the cause of the confusion I was having.

It would be nice if instead of defaulting to "Title" for the name of this field, "Name" were used instead, as that's a bit more descriptive and would not lead to the confusion we had. The name of this field is changeable -- I'd recommend changing it to "Name".